# Getting "Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"~0.0.0","webpack-de'" when run any ng command

Tags: node.js, angular, .net-core, angular6

I just get rid of this.
I am working on .net core with angular 6 in visual studio.
It's throwing this error while run project:

> Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from **project location**

And also getting new error each time when I restart VS2017.

**Versions:**

Angular CLI: 6.2.4

Node: 8.12.0

OS: win32 x64

Comment: did you execute npm install?

Comment: Yes, i do, i'm editing question with visions specification

Comment: To determine the problem is where, can you upload it to stackBlitz. if it is working  problem should be in your pc.

Comment: i tried this and working -- npm cache clean --force
-- npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular.  But then i get "Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document." this one

Comment: is that working now?

Comment: hopefully it is compiled. but not run. showing error as i described in prev. comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181650/discussion-between-asanka-and-unknown-coder).

Comment: try to remove the current node_modules folder then do npm install..